# Which preprocess hook do I use to fire some HTML altering PHP?

Tags: 7, theming

I have some PHP that ultimately says 'If this class is present in the HTML, add this string to the $additional_classes array'. Eg, something similar to:

```
$leftcol_empty = empty($content['leftcol']);
$additional_classes = !$leftcol_empty ? 'medium-8 medium-pull-4' : '';
```

Currently, I've put this at the top of my .tpl file and it works fine. However, I've been told I should move it to the 'theme preprocess function'.

I looked through my theme's template.php file and tried adding it to `my_theme_preprocess_page`, `my_theme_theme` and `my_theme_process_html` but it stopped working.

I've tried Googling for theme preprocesses but haven't found anything that works.

Would anyone know what preprocesses function I can use here?

Comment: You need to leverage the variables being passed and or add your own variable on ex. `$variables['additional_classes']` then output that in the template with `print $additional_classes;`. The preprocess hook you are using depends on which template you want to add it to.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `theme_preprocess_html(&$variables)` OR `my_module_preprocess_html(&$variables)`

in `$variables` you will see `$variables['classes_array']`

```
if(in_array('class_name', $variables['classes_array'])) {

  //Do your changes

}
```

Hope this will help.